# Testing private methods in R6 classes in R

Tags: r, r6

I am currently using R6 classes in a project.

I would like to write unit tests that also test the functionality of private methods that I am using (preferably by not going through the more complicated public methods that are using these private methods).

However, I can't access seem to access the private methods.

How do I best do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you be testing your private methods as they would normally be called from client code -- indirectly (e.g. from within public methods of your class), and *not* directly? The whole point of making methods and data members private is so that they aren't accessible from outside of the object instance.

Comment: Thanks @nrussell. For me, the point of writing unit-tests is in order to ensure that all functionality works as intended. For that purposes, unit-tests are best written at the lowest level possible. Writing a unit test for a public method that does something much more complicated (e.g. calls the private method hundreds of times in various settings) makes running the test and debugging failures much more complicated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a solution that does not require environment hacking or altering the class you want to test, but instead creating a new class that does the testing for you.

In `R6`, derived classes have access to `private` Methods of their base classes (unlike in `C++` or `Java` where you need the `protected` keyword to archieve the same result). Therefore, you can write a `TesterClass` that derives from the class you want to test. For example:

```
ClassToTest <- R6::R6Class(
  private = list(
    privateMember = 7,
    privateFunction = function(x) {
      return(x * private$privateMember)
    }
  )
)

TesterClass <- R6::R6Class(
  inherit = ClassToTest,
  public = list(
    runTest = function(x = 5) {
      if (x * private$privateMember != private$privateFunction(x))
        cat("Oops. Somethig is wrong\n")
      else
        cat("Everything is fine\n")
    }
  )
)

t <- TesterClass$new()
t$runTest()
#> Everything is fine
```

One advantage of this approach is that you can save detailed test results in the `TesterClass`.

Answer (score 3):

There is currently a way to access the private environment of an R6 object. However, since this is reaching into an object in an undocumented way, it may break in the future... I don't think that will happen any time soon though.

```
# Gets private environment from an R6 object
get_private <- function(x) {
  x[['.__enclos_env__']]$private
}

A <- R6::R6Class("A",
  private = list(x = 1)
)

a <- A$new()

get_private(a)$x
# [1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add a helper method `get` to your class:

```
...

A <- R6::R6Class(
  "A",
  private = list(
    private_print = function(){print("Ola")}
  ),
  public = list(
    get = function(name=NULL){
      # recursion
      if( length(name)>1 ){
        tmp <- lapply(name, self$get)
        names(tmp) <- name
        return(tmp)
      }
      if(is.null(name)){
        self$message("no input, returning NULL")
        return(NULL)
      }
      # self
      if(name=="self"){
        return(self)
      }
      # in self
      if( name %in% names(self) ){
        return(base::get(name, envir=self))
      }
      # private or in private
      if( exists("private") ){
        if(name=="private"){
          return(private)
        }else if(name %in% names(private) ){
          return(base::get(name, envir=private))
        }
      }
      # else
      self$message("name not found")
      return(NULL)
    }
  )
)

...
```

Than use it like this:

```
a <- A$new()

a$get("private_print")()
## [1] "Ola"
```